# Could not receive notifications on the endpoint after enabling Pub/Sub Authorization on push

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to enable the authentication on the endpoint provided to the pub/sub push. But enabling authentication results Unacked message count increase in the graph. I have provided the Cloud Functions Invoker,Service Account Token Creator,Service Account User,Pub/Sub Publisher, Cloud Run Invoker Roles to the service account associated with topic, But issue is still same. Does anyone know about this issue?
Delivery type : Push,
Endpoint URL: https://somedomain/save-response
Service Account Role: loud Functions Invoker,Service Account Token Creator,Service Account User,Pub/Sub Publisher, Cloud Run Invoker
Audience: https://somedomain/save-response
Message retention duration: 7 days
Expiry period: 31 days
Retry policy: Retry immediately

Comment: Can you share the detail of your pubsub push subscription configuration?

Comment: Delivery type : Push, 
Endpoint URL: https://somedomain/save-response
Service Account Role: loud Functions Invoker,Service Account Token Creator,Service Account User,Pub/Sub Publisher, Cloud Run Invoker
Message retention duration: 7 days
Expiry period: 31 days
Retry policy: Retry immediately

These are the configuration of the subscription.
 I am trying to receive the in-app purchases push notifications, enabling authentication goes in Unacked state, I am saving the response and header information in db and verified using postman passing header

Comment: Did you define an audience?

Comment: Audience is having same url as provided in Endpoint Url

Comment: Do you have any clues in the logs?

Comment: No there are no access/error logs for the provided endpoint.